# Solve the linear equation for infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me determine the value of **'a'** such that there are infinite many solutions for the given equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
2x &+ y &- 4z &= a   \\
4x &+ 3y &- 12z &= 5  \\
x &+ 2y &- 8z &= 7   \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Just solve the system in the normal elimination way. What do you get when you do that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their question, as [is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) in detail. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? If $a$ had a known value (for example, $a = 2$), would you be able to find out whether the system has no solutions, one solution, or infinitely many?

Comment: Do you know Cramer's Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Row-reduce the augmented matrix.  Then back-subsitute.
Note:  Looking at the associated homogeneous system, the determinant is zero.  Thus we just need to find one particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the system $Ax=b$ with

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&-4\\ \:4&3&-12\\ \:1&2&-8\end{pmatrix} $$

the second and third column are multiple therefore in order to have infinitely many solutions it suffices to find $a$ such that the system has at least one particular solution, that is find a solution to

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\ \:4&3\\ \:1&2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}a\\ -5\\-7\end{pmatrix} $$

In general term by [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem), we need that $A$ and the augmented matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&1&-4&-a\\ \:4&3&-12&-5\\ \:1&2&-8&-7\end{pmatrix} $$

have the same rank, that is a rank equal to $2$ in this case.